# unable to scrape a text file through a given link and store it in an output file

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to collect the weather data for year 2000 from [this](http://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/uscrn/products/daily01) site.

My code for the spider is:

```
    import scrapy
    from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
    from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

    class weather(CrawlSpider): 
        name = 'data'
        start_urls = [
       'https://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/uscrn/products/daily01/'
        ]
        custom_settings = {
               'DEPTH_LIMIT': '2',
        }
        rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=
        ('//table/tr[2]/td[1]/a',)),callback='parse_item',follow=True),
        )
        def parse_item(self, response):
          for b in response.xpath('//table')

            yield scrapy.request('/tr[4]/td[2]/a/@href').extract()
            yield scrapy.request('/tr[5]/td[2]/a/@href').extract()
```

The paths with 'yield' are the links to two text file and i want to scrape the data from these text files and store it separately in two different files but I don't know how to continue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't usually use `CrawlSpider` so I'm unfamiliar with it, but it seems like you should be able to create another xpath (preferably something more specific than `"/tr[4]/td[2]/a/@href"`) and supply a callback function.

However, in a "typical" scrapy project using `Spider` instead of `CrawlSpider`, you would simply yield a `Request` with another callback function to handle extracting and storing to the database. For example:

```
def parse_item(self, response):
  for b in response.xpath('//table')
      url = b.xpath('/tr[4]/td[2]/a/@href').extract_first()
      yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=extract_and_store)
      url = b.xpath('/tr[5]/td[2]/a/@href').extract_first()
      yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=extract_and_store)

def extract_and_store(self, response):
    """
    Scrape data and store it separately
    """
```